# django: Why can't I use __year lookup inside F() expression?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model with two `DateField`'s:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    finish_date = models.DateField()
```

This allows me to make queries that compare these fields, like

`ee=Event.objects.filter(finish_date=F('start_date'))`

and I can deal with the year of the date, like

`ee=Event.objects.filter(finish_date__year=2000)`

but when I try to use the same lookup `__year` inside `F()`, like this:

`ee=Event.objects.filter(finish_date__year=F('start_date__year'))`

, it fails:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'year' into field. Join on 'start_date' not permitted.`

Is there any reason for such behavior, or does it look like a bug?

I am using Django 1.11, and I see no such restricitions at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters .

Comment: What result supposed to return this query `Event.objects.filter(finish_date__year=F('start_date__year'))`?

Comment: All events such that start_date.year==finish_date.year

Comment: I've added one answer below. Hope it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
from django.db.models import F

Event.objects.annotate(finish_date_year=ExtractYear(F('finish_date'))).filter(start_date__year=F('finish_date_year'))
```

---

### Why `F('start_date__year')` didn't work?

From the [**Django Doc,**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

> An **`F()`** object represents ***the value of a model field or annotated column***.

So, the expression **`start_date__year`** isn't a **model field** or **annotated column**

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but it solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope its do the job. @AlexeyChernov